# Fastest way to remove duplicates from another table using two rows

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, join

The tables

```
CREATE TABLE `pending` (
  `auto_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`auto_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=68176 ;

CREATE TABLE `errors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `error` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `datechecked` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11553 ;
```

I am using the following code if I want to view records where pending's username and password combination dont have a match in errors:

```
SELECT `pending`.username, `pending`.password FROM `pending` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `errors` ON (
    `errors`.username = `pending`.username 
            AND 
    `errors`.password = `pending`.password
) WHERE (`errors`.username IS NULL)
```

To elaborate on what I mean by username and password combination is that given these tables, the result should be:

```
||||||pending table|||||||||
----------------------------
username    | password 
----------------------------
brian       | password1
brian       | password2
brian       | password3
brian       | password4



||||||errors table|||||||||
----------------------------
username    | password 
----------------------------
brian       | password2
brian       | password4


Result:

----------------------------
username    | password 
----------------------------
brian       | password1
brian       | password3
```

This works, but it takes a long time to complete. I am running this 20 times a day or so and each request is getting longer and longer as the errors table grows. I would say I am up to 5 minutes per SQL statement given their entry size by their AUTO_INCREMENT value.

I have a feeling I can make some sort of index using username and password and increase performance. Although I am not 100% sure, which is why I am asking SO.

Comment: I sure hope you aren't storing those passwords in plaintext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `NOT EXISTS` instead of the `LEFT JOIN`. MySQL is relatively slow with joins.

```
SELECT p.username, p.password
FROM   pending p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM errors WHERE (username, password) = (p.username, p.password))
```

Also, make sure you have indexes on pending (username, password) and errors (username, password).

```
CREATE INDEX username_password_idx ON pending (username, password);
CREATE INDEX username_password_idx ON errors (username, password);
```

Comment: The `NOT EXISTS` didn't help that much. I waited 10 minutes until I restarted mysql, but as soon as I added the indexes it took less than half a second.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ensure you have composite indexes on both `pending {username, password}` and `errors {username, password}`. I'm not too familiar with MySQL query optimizer, but most databases (and hopefully MySQL as well) should be able to use these indexes for an efficient MERGE JOIN.

Also, MySQL query optimizer might not be clever enough to realize that `WHERE (errors.username IS NULL)` does not actually require a full table scan (even with indexes). Try something like this:

```
SELECT `pending`.username, `pending`.password
FROM `pending` 
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM `errors`
        WHERE 
            `errors`.username = `pending`.username 
            AND `errors`.password = `pending`.password
    )
```